# Loading POD second time loses textures

Tags: objective-c, cocos3d

I assembled an app based on some of the example cocos3d code, and everything seems to work fine, except when I remove a node loaded from a POD file, and load it again.  In this case the model appears as all black as though no textures were loaded.

A basic flow allows the user to select a model from a list, and manipulate it (move, scale, etc.).  They can remove the model and select another one.  Selecting a different model works fine, but selecting one that was previously loaded appears as all black.

Code looks something like (summarized)...

```
    CC3PODResourceNode* rezNode = [CC3PODResourceNode nodeFromFile:[url path]];
    [modelNode addChild:rezNode];
    // manipulate
    [modelNode removeChild:rezNode];
```

The first time for a specific model this looks fine.  As mentioned, loading the same model after removing it results in a black (non-textured) node.  Nothing else changes in the world between (i.e. light, camera and other models stay the same).  The debug log shows the textures being removed with the node, and then added again when the model is loaded.

Comment: Look odd. If you ZIP up a small Xcode project that demonstrates the issue, and email it to support@brenwill.com, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks Bill.  I just sent it over - sorry I couldn't make it any smaller.

Comment: After trying out your app, I can see the issue you describe occurring on the iOS Simulator, but things run fine on an actual iOS device. All textures display correctly, even after multiple reloads. The iOS Simulator is notorious for this kind of lack of fidelity, particular in boundary conditions such as this. For this reason (and others, including performance), I never use the iOS Simulator.